# When declaring a function to a variable that variable stores the function or a reference?

Tags: javascript, object, variables

as I have just learnt when you assign an object to a variable, or constant, in that variable it is not stored the actual object but a reference value to a certain point in the memory where the actual value of the object is stored. Thus, as I have also learnt function are objects. So, my question is. When you are declaring a function into a variable, is it the same process? The function is stored somewhere in the memory and the variable stores a reference value that points to a certain place in the memory?

Comment: that would seem to be correct

Comment: Except for strings, numbers, null and booleans everything else in javascript are references - arrays, objects, functions etc. Weirdly even `undefined` is a reference

Comment: @slebetman everything in JavaScript is a value. It's just that sometimes a value is a reference. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/989920

Comment: @slebetman - *"Weirdly even undefined is a reference"* No, [`undefined` is a primitive value](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-undefined-type). You might be thinking of the fact that there's a global variable called `undefined` that contains the primitive value `undefined`, but it's not a reference of any kind. (Which is indeed weird, `undefined` should have been a keyword, like `null`.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, functions are objects, and yes the value stored in a variable for any object is a reference to the object, not a copy of it. That includes functions.

You can easily see that by making a change to the function object:

```js
const f1 = function fn() { };
const f2 = f1;
f1.someProperty = 42;
console.log(f2.someProperty); // 42
```

When you do:

```
const f1 = function() { };
```

you get something like this in memory *(details omitted)*:

```
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
f1:Ref13246−−−−−−−−−−−>|    (function)    |
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                       | name: "fn"       |
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note the value in `f1`, which I've shown here conceptually as `Ref13246`. It tells the JavaScript engine where to find that object.

Now if you do:

```
const f2 = f1;
```

you have something like:

```
                 
f1:Ref13246−−−−−−+
                 |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 +−−−−>|    (function)    |
                 |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
f2:Ref13246−−−−−−+     | name: "fn"       |
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Notice how `f2` and `f1` have the same value in them, a reference that says where the function is.

Now when we do:

```
f1.someProperty = 42;
```

that modifies the function:

```
                 
f1:Ref13246−−−−−−+
                 |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 +−−−−>|    (function)    |
                 |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
f2:Ref13246−−−−−−+     | name: "fn"       |
                       | someProperty: 42 |
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

You can see that new property on the function object regardless of which variable you get the reference from.

Comment: Just for clarification. `f1` and `f2` have the same value and `f2` doesn't reference `f1`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Right. Thanks, I should add a diagram, since that would otherwise be a valid conclusion.